# How to bitwise-and CFBitVector

Tags: objective-c, c, bit-manipulation, cfbitvector

I have two instances of `CFMutableBitVector`, like so:

```
 CFBitVectorRef ref1, ref2;
```

How can I do bit-wise operations to these guys? For right now, I only care about `and`, but obviously `xor`, `or`, etc would be useful to know.

Obviously I can iterate through the bits in the vector, but that seems silly when I'm working at the bit level. I feel like there are just some Core Foundation functions that I'm missing, but I can't find them.

Thanks,

Kurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well a

```
CFBitVectorRef
```

is a

```
typedef const struct __CFBitVector *CFBitVectorRef;
```

which is a

```
struct __CFBitVector {
    CFRuntimeBase _base;
    CFIndex _count;         /* number of bits */
    CFIndex _capacity;  /* maximum number of bits */
    __CFBitVectorBucket *_buckets;
};
```

Where

```
/* The bucket type must be unsigned, at least one byte in size, and
   a power of 2 in number of bits; bits are numbered from 0 from left
   to right (bit 0 is the most significant) */

typedef uint8_t __CFBitVectorBucket;
```

So you can dive in a do byte wise operations which could speed things up.  Of course being non-mutable might hinder things a bit :D

Comment: The underlying representation of CFBitVector is an implementation detail, and is therefore subject to change without warning. It should not be relied on in shipping software.

Comment: @bdash  Yes this is implementation dependent.  However it is predictable and the assumptions it is using can be tested.  In addition I don't see the implementation changing in the near future without significant changes in a lot of software.